# Trying to create multiple google docs from values in a sheet with a loop

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to use the values in a spreadsheet to create multiple Google Docs but I'm unsure about how to loop through each row. I'm getting an error saying: **data.forEach is not a function**

The code looks like this:

```
function manualIndividual() {
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getDataRange();
  var values = data.getValues();
  
  data.forEach(function(row) {
  
  var type = row[2];
  var taxNumber = row[3];
  var title = row[15];  
  var surname = row[16];
  var fullNames = row[17];
  var ID = row[18];
  
  if (type == "Personal Financial Services") {
  
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById("1pWe4TBF3_mlqglfoIrTO8d6O2fSra27lPt0Iy9Tjwjw");
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("17F678vzKcE7AaVqef0k-f96uHCOJeotv");
  var copy = file.makeCopy(surname + ',' + fullNames, folder);
  var doc = DocumentApp.openById(copy.getId());
  var body = doc.getBody();
  
  body.replaceText("{{FullNames}}", fullNames);
  body.replaceText("{{Surname}}", surname);
  body.replaceText("{{ID}}", ID);
  body.replaceText("{{IncomeTaxNumber}}", taxNumber);
  body.replaceText("{{Title}}", title)
  
  doc.saveAndClose();
  }
  })
}
```

Comment: forEach  only works on array types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### `data` is an instance of the class [range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range), it is not an array through which you can loop

This issue can be solved by looping through the values (which are a 2-dimensional array grid) instead, so:

```
values.forEach(function(row) {
  ...
}
```